# Can anyone explain the pigeon-hole encoding method in proportional logic

Tags: logic, satisfiability

Someone there who worked with cardinal contraindications within the framework of propositional logic? I have a problem understanding the pigeon-hole method. It is a method of satisfaction. I have been trying to understand these three patterns for several days now and I am desperate. Can anyone please explain these three formulas to me using an example?

[image]

I am also adding a link to the whole article

https://static.cambridge.org/content/id/urn:cambridge.org:id:article:S1471068413000112/resource/name/tlp2013026.pdf

I identified such an example . I also gave cardinal contains as an example

```
>=3 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
```

I have about the notation correctly and probably also the formula 10, correct me if I am wrong

```
            p13   p14   p15   p16   p17
      p22   p23   p24   p25   p26
p31   p32   p33   p34   p35
x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6    x7
```

formula 9

```
-p31 V x1
-p32 V x2
-p33 V x3
-p34 V x4
-p35 V x5
-p26 V x6
-p17 V x7

-p22 V x2
-p23 V x3
-p24 V x4
-p25 V x5
-p16 V x6

-p13 V x3
-p14 V x4
-p15 V x5
```

formula 10

```
p13 V p14 V p15 V p16 V p17
p22 V p23 V p24 V p25 V p26
p31 V p32 V p33 V p34 V p35
```

formula 11

```
p31 V P22
p22 V P13

p31 V p32 V P23 V -p14
p31 V p32 V p24 V -p15
```

Can you check if it is correct?

Comment: Do you understand already how formulas (6),(7),(8) encode the cardinality constraint? The interpretation is in the second paragraph of page $4$. Formulas (9),(10),(11) are a reduction of (6)-(8). I don't think there is too much value in interpreting (9)-(11) directly. They express the same as (6)-(8), but the latter is easier to read.

Comment: I understand formula 6-8,I adjusted the question, can you tell me if it is correct?

Comment: The paper spends a few pages explaining how to get (9)–(11) from (6)–(8).

Comment: sorry, my english is not good, so I did not explain it in the article